# How to resize an event in full calendar without the code "editable = true"

Tags: javascript, events, resize, fullcalendar

I need to manually resize the event in `fullcalendar` without the code `editable=true`, because I have added a dropdown inside the event and
to work its click I suppose prevent the editable property(`editable=false`). Now the dropdown is working but the resize property been disappeared. Even I tried the property resizable(`resizable=true`). How can I bring both the codes?

### sample code

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
theme: true,
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,agendaFourDay'
},
    views: {
        agendaFourDay: {
            type: 'agenda',
            duration: { days: 4 },
            buttonText: '4 day'
        },
    },

    defaultView: viewDefault,
    //minTime: '07:00:00',
    //maxTime: '21:00:00',
    allDaySlot: false,
    eventClick: updateEvent,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: selectDate,
    editable: false,
    resizable: true,
    events: "JsonResponse.ashx?eids=" + eIds + "&searchText=" + searchText,
    //events: {
    //    url: 'JsonResponse.ashx',

    //    type: 'POST',
    //    data: {
    //        eIds: $('#hdnCustomerIds').val()
    //    },
    //    error: function () {
    //        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    //    }
    //},
    defaultDate: dateDefault,
    eventDrop: eventDropped,
    eventResize: eventResized,
    eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
        debugger;
        // event.stopPropagation();
        $(element).find('.fc-title').prepend('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete-event-link" style="color:#fff">' + event.customerid + ',</a>');


        $(element).find('.fc-title').html('<select class="dropdown" style="color:black";" onchange="OnchangeEventStatus(this,'+event.id+')"><option >Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="opel">Opel</option><option value="audi">Audi</option></select>');


        $(element).find('.dropdown').click(function (e) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //stop click event, add deleted click for anchor link
        });

        $(element).find('.delete-event-link').click(function (e) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //stop click event, add deleted click for anchor link
            window.top.location.href = "/Sr_App/Customer_Profile.aspx?CustomerId=" + event.customerid;
        });

        //$(element).find('.fc-title').prepend('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete-event-link" style="color:#fff">' + event.customerid + ',</a>');
        element.qtip({
            content: {
                text: qTipText(event.start, event.end, event.description),
                title: '<strong>' + event.title + '</strong>'
            },
            position: {
                my: 'bottom left',
                at: 'top right'
            },
            style: { classes: 'qtip-shadow qtip-rounded' }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: i got the solution, just add the property `editable:false` for _fullCalendar_

`$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    selectable: true,
   editable:false,
 events: "JsonResponse.ashx?eids=" + eIds + "&searchText=" + searchText,
......
....
  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the solution, just add the property `editable: false` for *fullCalendar*

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    selectable: true,
    editable: false,
    events: "JsonResponse.ashx?eids=" + eIds + "&searchText=" + searchText,
    ......
    ....
});
```